# Knockout custom binding model is not getting updated

Tags: knockout.js

Recently we have upgraded the knockout version from 2.1 to 3.4 for some reason. The below code is throwing an error as "modelValue is not a function". in 3.4. The same code block is working fine in 2.1. Please help me to understand the issue.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var $el = $(element);

    // set a default if-empty value if none is provided
    if (typeof($el.data('if-empty')) === 'undefined') {
        $el.data('if-empty', 0);
    }
    else {
        $el.data('if-empty', parseInt($el.data('if-empty')));
    }

    // set a blur handler on the element to set the model value
    //  need to use blur event instead of change event, since IE doesn't always
    //  trigger the change event when the text input is cleared
    $el.on('blur', function() {
        var $elem = $(this);
        var modelValue = valueAccessor();
        var prefix = ($el.attr("numberprefix") || '').toString().trim();
        var elemVal = $elem.val().replace(/[,]/g, '').replace(prefix, '').trim();

        // check for invalid number
        if (isNaN(elemVal)) {
            $elem.addClass('invalidInput');
            $elem.after('<span class="errorSpan"><br />Numeric Only</span>');
            return;
        }

        // clear the errors
        $elem.parent().find('.errorSpan').remove();
        $elem.removeClass('invalidInput');

        // get the new value
        var newValue = (elemVal.length == 0)
            ? $elem.data('if-empty')
            : parseInt(elemVal);

        // set the new model value
        modelValue(newValue);

    });
},
update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var $elem = $(element);
    var updatedVal = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    var prefix = ($elem.attr("numberprefix") || '').toString().trim();

    // set the value of the element
    //ko.utils.setTextContent(element, numberWithCommas(updatedVal, prefix));

    var value = numberWithCommas(updatedVal, prefix)
    if ((value === null) || (value === undefined))
        value = "";

    if ($elem.is(":input")) {
        $elem.val(value);
    }
    else {
        $elem.html(value);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type=text id="txtNetProfitLastLastYear" numberprefix='$' data-bind="numericFormatBinding: LastLastYear.NetProfitBeforeTaxes()"/>
```

Comment: If you're going to use Knockout, use Knockout. You lose all of the benefits of using it when you use jquery in that way. Anyway, you probably just need to remove the parens in your binding. You're effectively binding against the value of the observable, not the observable itself.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working.

Comment: @JeffMercado Make your comment an answer

Comment: @JeffMercado We want to have your answer!